# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

well im making a muter bot and when i use it says : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('l!mute '):
        role = message.guild.get_role(***role-id***)
        print(role) ***it shows role name***
        se = message.content
        mute = se.replace("l!mute ", "")
        user = mute
        channel = client.get_channel(message.channel.id)
        await channel.send(user+' ro behesh dadam rolee '+str(role), reference=message)
        guild = client.get_guild(***server-id***)
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

i tried eveything that i know

Comment: Why is user = to mute? What are the * for? Is this even python? 

User should be equal to a discord member like a mention in the text or something.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly setting `user` to a `str` by using the `message.content`.

Assuming the command usage is: `l!mute {user_mention}`, you can get the first mention of a message with the [Message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) attribute.

```
if not message.mentions: #  If no user is mentioned, send an error message
    return await message.reply("Mention a user to mute.")

user = message.mentions[0] #  Message.mentions returns a List
```

Relevant documention: [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message), [Message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)